# Hiding header row in dc.js

Tags: dc.js

I am following this tutorial in learning D3v3

http://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/6077996

```
    .dimension(timeDimension)
    .group(function(d) { return "List of all earthquakes corresponding to the filters"
     })
    .size(10)                           // number of rows to return
    .columns([
      function(d) { return d.dtg; },
      function(d) { return d.lat; },
      function(d) { return d.long; },
      function(d) { return '<a href=\"http://maps.google.com/maps?z=11&t=m&q=loc:' + d.lat + '+' + d.long +"\" target=\"_blank\">Google Map</a>"},
      function(d) { return '<a href=\"http://www.openstreetmap.org/?mlat=' + d.lat + '&mlon=' + d.long +'&zoom=11'+ "\" target=\"_blank\"> OSM Map</a>"}
    ])
    .sortBy(function(d){ return d.dtg; })
    .order(d3.ascending);
```

I am trying to remove this portion "List of all earthquakes corresponding to the filters" as a first row in the table. However, i tried many solutions such as removing the `group` and it just renders the table unusable. Anyone has any solutions?

Thanks!. I am extremely new to D3 and just trying out!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use

```
dataTable
    .showGroups(false)
```

to hide the grouping rows ([documentation](https://dc-js.github.io/dc.js/docs/html/dc.dataTable.html#showGroups__anchor)).

Unfortunately there is currently no way to stop dc.js from grouping the data table, but if the `.group()` function returns a constant value then you will end up with one group.

Do not confuse this `.group()` function with those on other charts. [It's completely different.](https://github.com/dc-js/dc.js/issues/855)